# FormsAuthentication in .NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` en .net Core. I used that method in asp net with `using System.Web.Security` but in asp net doesn't work. Is there any way i can use that method in .net core?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try with cookie Authentication in .net core,you could  add the ticket to cookie with  `HttpContext.SignInAsync`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string somestr)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.xxx, somestr));
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(principal));
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

regist the service in DI container:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie( m =>
            {
                m.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("....");
                m.Cookie.Name = "....";
               
            });
```

configure the middleware:

```
...
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
...
```

for more details,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-an-authentication-cookie-1)